# How to measure signal with ADC from position sensor 5 meters away?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, stm32, spi, position-sensor

I want to design a new board that includes an ADC (AD7606C-4) and STM32.
I need to measure 3 analog signals from a position sensor (PDP90A).
The distamce of the position sensor from the A2D is ~5 Meters.

The spec of the sensor:
[image]

This is simplified block diagram:
[image]

A fact that is important to note, the dynamic range according to preliminary tests we did will be from -0.5 volts to 0.5 volts (we will not use the entire dynamic range of the sensor, which is -4v to 4v, because the space in the system is limited).

My question is: do I need some op-amp/amplifier or should it be okay with this distance?

EDIT: The required precision is 1/2 LSB.
the A/D resolution is 16bit
The input impedance of ADC is 1MegaOhm (Internal)

Comment: You do not say what sort of precision you need to maintain.  But, this is the 21st century, and assuming that you can get parts, the most reliable way to get that data cleanly is to have a board with the ADC, signal conditioning, and a little processor that communicates _digitally_ with the central processor board.

Comment: @TimWescott When I am going to present my plan and present alternatives, I first need to give a logical explanation as to whether there is an effect at a distance of 5 meters, because if there is an effect, I will not know how to explain it in this case. I will only know how to say "the signal distorts on the way or doesn't distort but I can't explain why"

Comment: I would replace the included cable with a pair of coaxial cables (or three if you want the sum output too), but would otherwise not expect the cable length to have a large effect given the very low bandwidth. You won't get anywhere close to 1/2 LSB (38uV) given the 300uV rms output noise though, at least not without a lot of signal conditioning.

Comment: @user1850479 I will be okay with 300uV RMS output noise. thats all the problem with 5 meters cable or maybe there are another issues?

Comment: 15khz and ~12 bits at half a volt would be a really bad headphone jack. You can plug a 5m long headphone cable made of simple wire into a stereo and have much better SNR then you are hoping for. I recommend coaxial to be extremely safe, but your requirements are not hard to achieve. Anything better than untwisted coat hangers should work.

Comment: Perform the Analog to Digital Conversion locally near the sensor, then use differential signaling for the "long" distance. There are RS485 drivers available which can easily make 10MBit. Where does the supply from the sensor come from? Is it the same ground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, there is not much you need or can do. The PDP90A sensor is a piece of lab equipment used to report the position of laser on a photodiode of sorts. There are amplifier circuits in the sensor for I/V conversion and to perform various difference and summing operations. The output signals are 2 bipolar +/- 4 V, and 1 unipolar 0-4 V. All are band limited to 15 kHZ. The inputs are +/- 5 V at 35 mA and a common GND.

The six signals are available on a specified Hirose style connector with a 1.5 m cable to the sensor head.

The typical application plugs the cable into an application box, sold by the sensor vendor, that does a/d conversion, DSP, and other general compute functions.

The ADC selected is specifically designed for this type of data acquisition application. The inputs go directly to a high impedance differential amplifier with a +/- 5 V range. A 15-20 kHz low pass anti-aliasing filter is provided as well as a simultaneous T/H amplifier, and of course 16 bit A/D.

If you could crack the case and jumper wire sensor outputs directly your board there would be nothing to do.

Since you can’t, there will be 1.5 m of vendor cable in place. The best you can do is extend the cable 3.5 m with the best matching cable and connectors. From a signal quality perspective the difference is nil. The reason is the signal bandwidth of 15 kHz. The driver doesn’t see the cable, it sees only the high impedance input of the ADC buffer. There are no reflections, no terminations or filters to put in place. The ADC low pass filter is perfect and probably better than you could add.

The only other issue is noise. First, conducted noise your board sends down the wire on power and ground wires, make sure it’s dead quite, get an expert. Second, inducted noise into the cable from the environment (60 Hz and harmonics, etc). Of course more cable is not good.

Research the cable and connectors. Talk to the sensor vendor, tell them about 5m requirement:

1. What do they think, any concerns?
2. Do they have extensions, can they build one?
3. Can then build sensor with 5m, eliminate connectors?
4. Is the cable shielded?
5. What does their ADC box look like inside?

Comment: Thank you for an amazing answer that sorted out my thinking, the box you are talking about we have it but we need to design custom board. regarding the ADC I cannot destroy a box but I know that my ADC is good enough (AD7606) that knows these signals and even now we can work with it, the only problem left for us (me) to solve is the length of the cable, I want to save the needs with an additional MCU to the other side and transmit a differential with RS422 to save a lot of money and extra work
About the noise what can I do to filter the 60HZ noise and Harmonics,LPF with 15kHz will be enough?

Comment: Again, I would stress the value of talking to the vendor of the sensor about your need for a 5 meter cable. You need to move the ADC outside of the test chamber with the rest of the computerized test equipment, etc. Ask the first four questions at least.

Comment: The best thing you can do is to keep the noise off your signals. The most effective way is a good cable shield. Again, it depends on what is supplied with the cable on the sensor. A half shielded cable isn’t that helpful.

Comment: Filtering out any more, like 60 Hz is hard with analog as the components get large and the filters complex if you want to leave any of your signal.  A notch filter in the digital side may be a possibility. An audio engineer would be a better person to ask about both cables and filters here.

Comment: It would be interesting to know more about the application as this type of sensor has limited purposes. Unless you’re trying to close the loop on some fast steerable mirrors or something, there’s usually a human in the loop and BW drops significantly.

Comment: The sensor itself samples the oscillations from the mirrors of an optical system whose purpose is to perform IOCT for the eyes. I am a medical worker.

Answer (score 1):

The longer the wire, the more it will be affected by interference. It can happen internally, inside the cable, or externally.

If happening inside the sensor cable, this phenomenon is called **crosstalk** - a voltage variation on one of the signal lines affecting the others.

The outside world is also full of electromagnetic signals, and your 5-meter cable can act as a receiving antenna. This is known as electromagnetic interference or **EMI**.

Here is a diagram illustrating these phenomena, taken from this [Actelis Networks](https://actelis.com/technology-2/copper-broadband-technologies/cross-talk/) post.

[image: Crosstalk in transmission lines, source Actelis Networks]

Comment: Great explanation but tell me what options I have to prevent the EMI and Crosstalks in my case, coaxial cable will do the job?
That I think about it again in depth, an ethernet cable can transfer hundreds of meters! Why would 5 meters cause so many problems?

Comment: Ethernet has special design techniques that allows for such long distance high speed signaling. Some of these techniques are differential signaling, pre and post emphasis, pre-distortion, shielded cable, and controlled impedance design. Are you doing any of that?